# Minimization a function with respect to a norm

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, convex-optimization

I have troubles undersatnding the solution of the LP from a textbook given as:

$\min c^Tx $ s.t. $\|x\|_2^2 \le 1$ where $c\not=0.$

The textbook started by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get:

$c^Tx \ge -\|c\|_2\|x\|_2 \ge -\|c\|_2 \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $\|x\|_2 \le 1$ $\quad\quad$

(I find it uneasy relating the C-S inequality: $|uv|\le |u||v|, \forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to $c^T x$)

The text continued: the inequality becomes equality when $x=-c/\|c\|_2.$

Conclusion: $\min c^Tx = -\|c\|_2$.

Comment: This question is unclear. What is LP? What is $c'$? Is it a derivative of $c$? The inequality $-\|c\|_2\|x\|_2 \ge \|c\|_2 \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is generally false.

Comment: It was just a typo.

Comment: I removed the linear-programming tag because the constraints are not linear.

Answer (score 1):

From Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in any inner product space we get $|c\circ x|\leq \|c\|\cdot\|x\|$, so $c\circ x\geq -\|c\|\cdot\|x\|.$ If $\|x\|\leq 1$ then $\|c\|\cdot\|x\|\leq \|c\|$, so $c\circ x\geq -\|c\|$.

On the other hand, if we take $x=-c/\|c\|$ (this point satisfies $\|x\|=1$) we obtain $$c\circ x = -\frac{c\circ c}{\|c\|} = -\frac{\|c\|^2}{\|c\|}=-\|c\|.$$

This shows that $c\circ x$ is never smaller than $-\|c\|$ but it attains this value somewhere in the domain. This shows that this is a minimal velue.

One can ask how do we know to consider $x=-c/\|c\|$. It's known that the equality in C-S inequality $|c\circ x|\leq \|c\|\|x\|$ holds iff $c$ and $x$ are linearly dependent. Moreover $\|c\|\cdot\|x\|=\|c\|$ iff $\|x\|=1$. These gives the way to find the argument $x$ minimizing our function.

Comment: I assume $\circ$ means transpose? On what premise is $c\circ x\geq -\|c\|\cdot\|x\|$? Where from the negative?

Comment: Is it correct to say that for such questions, it suffices to find the value of $x$ which makes the C-S inequality linearly dependent?

Comment: Generally if you have to (1. step) calculate $\min\{f(x):x\in X\}$ you can show that $f(x)\geq m$ for any $x\in X$ and (2. step) that $f(x)=m$ for some $x\in X$. In the second step we tried to check when our inequality is equality. Two conditions must be satisfied: equality in the first equality (linear 'negative' dependence) and the second one (norm of $\|x\|$). If we use different inequality, we use different condition for inequality being equality.

Comment: Could you elaborate on $c\circ c = \|c\|^2$? Can $x=-\|c\|/c^T$? I see that $c^Tx = -\frac{c^T\|c\|}{c^T} = - \|c\|$

Comment: $\circ$ is an inner product, co $u\circ v=u^Tv = \sum u_iv_i$. Therefore $c\circ c=\sum c_i^2 = \|c\|^2$. No, it can't, since what you can do is to multiply vector by a number, divde vector by a nonzero number, but you can't divide number by a vector. What is $1/[1,2]$?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the classical method for constrained optimization. The Lagrange multipliers! Introduce a dummy variable y and consider the problem min$c^{T}x $ subject to $\left\|x \right\|^{2}+y^{2}=1$. Then L=$c_{1}x_{1}+...+c_{n}x_{n}-\lambda (x_{1}^{2}+....+x_{n}^{2}+y^{2})$ and using partial differentiation we get $c_{1}=2\lambda x_{1}, ....,c_{n}=2\lambda x_{n}, -2\lambda y=0$ and since $\lambda\neq 0$ (because otherwise we would get x=0 which is certainly not a minimizer) we obtain y=0 and $\left\|x \right\| =1$. Thus $\left\|c \right\|^{2}=4\lambda ^{2}\left\|x \right\|$ =4$\lambda ^{2} $. Since we want to minimize we choose $\lambda =-\frac{\left\|c \right\|}{2}$ and obtain $x_{1}=-\frac{c_{1}}{\left\| c\right\|},....,x_{n}=-\frac{c_{n}}{\left\|c \right\|}$
and hence the minimum is
-$\frac{\left\|c \right\|^{2}}{\left\|c \right\|}$=
-$\left\|c \right\|$.! There are also other ways to solve such problems eg by Fenchel duality, where we produce a dual problem much easier to solve!

Comment: Fenchel duality requires the objective function to be convex. Oh Lagrangian works!

Answer (score 0):

Since the linear map $f(x)= c^Tx$ is open it is clear that the solution must lie on the boundary $\|x\|=1$.
Cauchy Schwartz gives $|f(x)| \le \|c\|$ for all $\|x\| = 1$, so in particular,
$f(x) \ge -\|c\|$ for all $x$. Since $f(-{c \over \|c\|}) = -\|c\|$, we see that $-{c \over \|c\|}$ is a minimiser.